# Strectch div to fit background image

Tags: html, css

Can I stretch a div to fit the background image's width and height using only CSS? And if yes, how?
Div has width and height unset.

I am **NOT** asking how to scale the image into a div.
I am **NOT** asking how to scale the image into a div with specific width and height.

ie.

```
   <div class="banner" 
        styles="width: auto; height: auto; background-image: url(unknown-size-img.jpg)">
   </div>
```

Comment: Why not just show the image instead of making it a background image using an img tag? What's the use case here?

Comment: Use background-size:cover; also for div use a min-height instead of auto;

Comment: *ONLY* CSS? No, you can't.

Comment: @HaukurHaf Thnx

Comment: @AndyHolmes It's a POC question

Comment: Given the use case you might get a better POC response

Comment: It has nothing to do with the post marked as duplicate

Answer (score 2):

I have a suggestion, but may not be a good method.

Put the same image as a  tag inside the DIV. So the container div will take the same size of the . Then make the  zero opacity and may be pointer-events 'none' like below

```
<div class="banner" styles="width: auto; height: auto; background-image: url(unknown-size-img.jpg)">
      <img src="unknown-size-img.jpg" alt="image" title="image" style="opacity:0 ; pointer-events: none" />
</div>
```

Comment: hello, it seems the good idea , maybe to think about content layed over too  https://jsfiddle.net/yhdpw8v4/ ;) attribute style without S